# Eloquent ORM error: Column not found: 1054

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a problem with hasOne relation, but i don't understand why.
An article just a supplier. So in the Article model placed a foreign key pointing to the primary key suppliers.

```
class Article extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $softDelete = true;

    // Accesibles to edit
    //protected $fillable = array( 'code', 'name', 'size', 'price', 'redial', 'supplier_id', 'count', 'description', 'colour' );
    protected $fillable = array('*');

    // prevent edit
    protected $guarded = array( 'updated_at', 'created_at', 'id' );


    public function supplier() {
        return $this->hasOne('Supplier');
    }

}
```

and

```
class Supplier extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $softDelete = true;

    protected $fillable = array('*');

    protected $guarded = array('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');


    public function article() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Article');
    }

}
```

Migrations:

```
Schema::create('articles', function($table)
        {
            // DB Engine
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            // Columns
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('code')->unique();
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('colour')->nullable();
            $table->integer('count')->unsigned();
            $table->float('price')->unsigned();
            $table->float('redial')->default(100)->unsigned();

            $table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers');

            // Additionals columns
            $table->softDeletes(); // Never removed, only sets a date of deletion in delete_at column
            $table->timestamps();    // Set created_at updated_at columns automatically

            // Index and others atributtes
            $table->index('code');
        });
```

and

```
Schema::create('suppliers', function($table)
        {
            // DB Engine
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            // Columns
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('full_name', 50);
            $table->string('company', 50);

            // Additionals columns
            $table->softDeletes(); // Never removed, only sets a date of deletion in delete_at column
            $table->timestamps();    // Set created_at updated_at columns automatically

        });
```

Article Controller:

```
public function create()
    {
        $article = new Article;
        $article->code = Input::get('code');
        $article->name = Input::get('name');
        $article->description = Input::get('description');
        $article->size = Input::get('size');
        $article->colour = Input::get('colour');
        $article->count = Input::get('count');
        $article->price = Input::get('price');
        $article->redial = Input::get('redial');

        $supplier = Supplier::find(Input::get('supplier_id'));

        $article->supplier->associate($supplier);

        $article->save();

        return View::make('articles.show')->with( array('article' => $article) );
    }
```

The output:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'suppliers.supplier_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `suppliers` where `suppliers`.`deleted_at` is null and `suppliers`.`supplier_id` is null limit 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `foreign key` in your `suppliers` table, so add this in the migration of `suppliers`

```
$table->integer('article_id');
```

Since you used `hasOne('Supplier')` in your `Article` model then `Laravel` will look for a related model in `suppliers` table using `article_id` which would be related to a model in the parent table (articles) using `id`. In other words, records in your `articles` table will make a relation with `suppliers` using something like this:

Table `articles` (Parent):

```
id | ...
 1 | ...
 2 | ...
```

Table `suplierss` (Child):

```
id | article_id | ... 
 1 |     1      | ... //<-- article_id in this table is id in articles table
 2 |     2      | ... //<-- article_id in this table is id in articles table
```

In `articles` table `primary Key/id` refers to `foreign key/article_id` in `suppliers` table.

In other way, you have references of `suppliers` in `articles` table using `article_id` so you should use in your `suppliers` table:

```
public function article() {
    return $this->hasMany('Article');
}
```

Then use the reverse relation (`belongsTo`) in opposite model (Article) use:

```
// In Article Model
public function supplier() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Supplier');
}
```

Comment: Mmm... But having a reference is the article not the supplier

Comment: So, suppliers hasMany articles would be the solution?

Comment: Yes, I think so, you did it other way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause is looking for `suppliers.supplier_id` - but in your CREATE schema, this isn't specified.

```
Schema::create('suppliers', function($table)
        {
            // DB Engine
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            // Columns
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('supplier_id');  // consider adding an integer for supplier id.
            $table->string('full_name', 50);
            $table->string('company', 50);

            // Additionals columns
            $table->softDeletes(); // Never removed, only sets a date of deletion in delete_at column
            $table->timestamps();    // Set created_at updated_at columns automatically

        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure. In article: 

$table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned();            $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers');

Foreign is supplier_id in article, and primary key is "id" in suppliers... I don't understand